# How to change a word using jquery if else statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, if-statement

I am using Jquery UI Range Slider with fixed minimum (http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin)
for a user to select a maximum journey length in hours. The slider ranges from 0hours - 48 hours.
I need the word "hours" to change to "hour" when it is less than or equal to 1.
Please see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/t69wg/1/

My jquery:

```
$(function () {
$("#slider-range-min").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 24,
    min: 1,
    max: 48,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").text(ui.value + $timeUnit);
    }
});

$timeUnit = " hours";


$("#amount").text($("#slider-range-min").slider("value") + $timeUnit);
});
```

I think I would use an if else statement, something like:

```
if (value < 0) {
    $timeUnit = " hour";
}else {
    $timeUnit = " hours";
};
```

I am new to jquery so sorry for stupid question!

Comment: There's no such thing as a jquery if-statement, it's javascript.

Comment: I'm not good at either, hence asking the question - thanks for letting me know.

Comment: OK, jQuery is the stuff like `$(...)` everything else you have is javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On slide callback, you can use:

### --DEMO--

```
$timeUnit = ui.value > 1 ? " hours" :  " hour";
```

Comment: Thank u works brilliantly, but the initial value is not displayed on page load? The amount only appears now when you move the slider?

Comment: Don't know why i removed it, sorry, updated jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(function () {

$("#slider-range-min").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 24,
    min: 1,
    max: 48,
    slide: function (event, ui) {

$timeUnit=(ui.value <=1)?" hour":" hours";

});
```